# Bootstrap(3.2.0) responsive not working in Inside Iframe in iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a page with following

```
 <title>xxxx</title> 
 <meta name="description" content="xxx"> 
 <meta name="keywords" content="xxx">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hi">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I am embedding iframe as following

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>xxxxx</title>
```

Bootstrap is not working and i have also written some media queries as follows

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 768px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

 ///some css is here
}
@media(min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 768px) { 
///some css is here
}
```

Responsiveness of bootstrap and media queries are not working in iPhone from 3 to 6 any model.
I have also tried the following in iframe link

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
```